# PostgreSQL big XML file parse

Tags: xml, postgresql, bigdata, large-files

I am new in PostgreSQL. I am making a database and I have a problem with an XML file. This XML file has 986 MB or 1029949618 bytes, and I tried some scripts but I have an error like:

```
Error: out of memory
Detail: String of 1029949618 bytes is too long for encoding conversion.
```

How to fix it? Please help me.

This is a script which I tried:

```
            create or replace function xml_import(filename text)
        returns xml
        volatile
        language plpgsql as
        $f$
            declare
                content bytea;
                loid oid;
                lfd integer;
                lsize integer;
            begin
                loid := lo_import(filename);
                lfd := lo_open(loid,1029949618);
                lsize := lo_lseek(lfd,0,2);
                perform lo_lseek(lfd,0,0);
                content := loread(lfd,lsize);
                perform lo_close(lfd);
                perform lo_unlink(loid);

                return xmlparse(document convert_from(content,'WIN1251'));
            end;
        $f$;

        select xml_import('D:\SQLregisterUkr\15.1-EX_XML_EDR_UO.xml');
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reasonably have an `xml` of such a size in the database. It is below the theoretical limit of 1GB, but as you notice, the problems start much earlier, since the whole object will have to reside in RAM.

You cannot reasonably process XML of that size in PostgreSQL anyway.

If all you want to do is store the large file, then either don't store it in the database or use a Large Object.